# Eliminating columnnames after reading table in R

Tags: r

New in R. I haven´t find an answer for this.

When I read a table in R, it introduces a V1, V2, V3, names in the columns. HOw can I get rid of them?. The file doesn´t have column names. This is my code. I have tried with txt and csv files.

```
write.table(test,file="tab.txt",append=F,quote=F)
write.csv(test,file="tab.csv",append=F,quote=F)
tab <- read.table("tab.txt",header=T)
tab2 <- read.csv("tab.csv",header=T)

  X V1 V2         V3         V4         V5
1    1 -1 -1 -0.5418994 -1.0000000 -0.1967213
2   10 -1 -1 -0.5418994 -0.3514739 -0.1967213
3  100 -1 -1 -0.5418994 -1.0000000 -1.0000000
4 1000 -1 -1 -0.5418994 -0.3514739 -0.1967213
5 1001 -1 -1 -0.5418994 -0.3514739 -0.1967213
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to get rid of them?  Aesthetics?  Functionality?

Comment: Or do you want to replace the column names by something useful? Your question is unclear now.

Comment: I want simply the column names as [,1],[,2]....instead of V1, V2.

Answer (score 2):

Make it into a matrix as I've done here with the cars data set:

```
cars2 <- as.matrix(cars)
colnames(cars2) <- NULL
head(cars2)

## > head(cars2)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    4    2
## [2,]    4   10
## [3,]    7    4
## [4,]    7   22
## [5,]    8   16
## [6,]    9   10
```

A data.frame object needs column names (or it's particularly difficult to force no names).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did that but I want to keep the rownames from the original dataset. When I do the NULL everything revert to the matrix format.